# Any way to bypass redirect from old blog to new location

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog

In using Google and Bing to seek topics related to Sharepoint 2010, I get lots of hits to a blog called GetThePoint at http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/

Recently, I notice that there is an immediate redirection to the world of Office 365 where, upon a little digging, this blog entry related to a Sharepoint 2010 issue is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas to find its location ?

Comment: Whats the link to the post you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears they are either doing an IIS-level redirect or redirect via code.  In either case there is no way to get to the page content before it redirects you (its not serving up actual content).

Answer (score 1):

The original blog is in Google Cache for the time being.  You might have to be a little creative about how you get there, but is is there.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:spJL4zzvbPUJ:sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us